# keep a button fixed, but inside body

Tags: html, css

```
body{
    max-width:1366px;
}

.gotop{
    position:fixed;
    right:9px;
    bottom:7px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:25px;
}
```

`gotop` is a button to scroll page on top and it must not be scrollable, i.e. must be `fixed`.

Problem is on monitors greater than 1366 px. The button is far right from the body.

How to keep it fixed, but inside body?

Comment: In this case I would use percentages, for example: `right:10%`

Comment: Used percentage instead of px.

Comment: @enxaneta, using percentages the button will have different right distance (relative to body) on different monitors.

Comment: In this case you should consider showing more code.

Comment: @enxaneta, there is no more code, of course.

Comment: so basic thing - there is no solution. In case I would ask about `regex` or a complex `php` function - 10 answers in two minutes.

Comment: So basic yet you're here asking for help? People who live in glass houses...

Comment: @AshleyBrown, don't understand `glass houses` but whatever they are - yes, I'm here asking for help, for a basic `html-css` code.

Comment: @puerto [see here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/people_who_live_in_glass_houses_shouldn%27t_throw_stones) for glass houses proverb. Back to the question at hand though - CSS is only part of the code. It obviously is applied to HTML, which is missing. Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either in a JsFiddle (or similar), or as an edit to the original quesiton, so we can help you further.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this could be solved using `calc()`, in a similar way the technique described here works, https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to omit `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` values for the fixed button. This way it will be sticked to the container:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200vh; /* for scrolling demo */
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px; /* button width plus margin */
  top: 30%; /* or whatever you need */
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```css
body{
    max-width:1366px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
}

.gotop{
    position:absolute;
    right:25px;
    bottom:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button class='gotop'>TOP</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `body` is not 100% !

Comment: If you want 1366px. you can change.

Comment: and where is then the solution? On greater monitors the button is outside of body!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using max-width on the body... you should put it on a div that wraps everything in the page instead.

Then place your button at the bottom of wrapper with the following CSS applied. Tweak the values to get a better position if you need it.

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height:200vh;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:400px;
  background: #000;
}

.holder{
  position: absolute;
  top:92.5%;
  right:0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.button{
  height:30px;
  width: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left:-70px; /* minus width */
  bottom:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="holder">
    <button class="button">Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you see - your button is scrollable with the rest of content ?

Answer (score 0):

What you asking is rather an old way of doing things but it can be achieved.

- Set the width of body.
- Set fixed element to center.
- Offset center by width of body and fixed element.

```css
html,
body {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:1px solid #111;
}

.gotop {
  position: fixed;
  left:50%;
  bottom: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:40px;
  background:#eee;
  margin-left:60px;/*half width of body minus width of gotop*/
}
```

```html
<div class="gotop">TOP</div>
```

Comment: how do you know what is `half width of body`? It has no fixed width.

Comment: you could probably use a combination of `calc()` and `vw` to work out the margin-left value.

Comment: To be honest I would suggest you rethink how you are compiling this page in the first place. It is not good practice to manipulate the body in this manner.

Comment: @DreamTeK, `body`, or `container`, or `wrapper`... problem with keeping fixed element inside is the same.